# Saving Level in XML

Tags: c#, xna

Greetings to everyone. I am creating a Level with objects (Tiles, Obstacles, Character). I am experiencing a problem. The serialization is successfully made, but I get empty Lists. I want to serialize and save the attributes of each object. For example:

```
public class Obstacle 
{
    public Texture2D ob_tex;
    public Rectangle ob_rec;
    public bool ob_clic;


    Obstacle() { } // Create Constructor
}
```

I use this code to save the level:

```
public class Level 
{

    public List<Obstacle> obstacles;
    public LevelFile levelfile;

    public Level()
    {
        obstacles = new List<Obstacle>();
    }

    public class LevelFile
    {
        public List<Obstacle> obstacles;
    }

    public void Save(String path/*, LevelFile levelfile*/)
    {
        levelfile = new LevelFile();
        levelfile.obstacles = obstacles;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LevelFile));
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, levelfile);
        }   
    }
```

}

But I get an xml file which is like this:

```
<LevelFile<obstacles /></LevelFile>
```

And nothing in it(Rectangle value, Texture and bool)....

Comment: I'm not sure about this, so comment rather than answer... Don't you have to add some 'decoration' attribute to your members so they are serialized?

Comment: Other thing to check, are the members public access read/write? (ie either public members or public properties with both getter and setter public)

Comment: In short, it would help to show bits of your Obstacle class!

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to your code you're saving a new LevelFile() which has an obstacles member that's a list, which you set from the obstacles member in your Level() constructor, which is an empty list.  Thus the XML is right, you are outputting a file with an empty list which shows as the empty tag.

So it looks like your code is correct.  If you add an obstacle to your list in the constructor or save, you'll see that it's actually working correctly:

```
public Level()
{
    obstacles = new List<Obstacle>
        {
            new Obstacle { /* set your properties here */ }
        };
}
```

Comment: ...The thing is that I already have a seperate class called "Obstacle" and in my main file I add objects to this class List. So, I want to copy the List in my main class to the one that I want to save!!!